# Updating the DOM with List of Objects from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, performance, web, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have a web application that stores data with Firebase Real-Time Database that uses the object (list) of objects to update the DOM. The list of objects is sorted and grouped according to some rules that the user chooses.

What I am currently doing is every time the user adds, deletes, or modifies the data, an on value callback is triggered and the entire list is returned in the callback to recreate the list. Then the list is sorted, the DOM element has its innerHTML cleared, and new elements are created. This means that even if the user updates a single property that does not affect the sorting or grouping, the entire DOM is recreated. This is what I am trying to improve.

How can I improve the process to reduce the amount of the DOM that is deleted and recreated?

Current Pseudocode (as requested):

```
database.ref().on(“value”, function (snapshot) {
    let val = snapshot.val();
    // Group Objects
    let groups = groupObjects(val.list, val.groupBy);
    // Sort Groups
    let sortedGroups = groups.map(function (group) { 
        return sortObjects(group, val.sortBy)
    });
    // Update DOM
    listElement.innerHTML = “”;
    sortedGroups.forEach(function (group) {
        let row = document.createElement(“div”);
        group.forEach(function (item) {
            row.appendChild(createItemElement(item));
        });
        listElement.appendChild(row);
    });
});
```

As you can see, simply adding or replacing elements by getting listeners for what has change is insufficient as it may change how the elements are sorted entirely.

Comment: Answer below. In future questions please **show** the minimal actual code that reproduces what you're asking about, instead of describing it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an `on("value"` listener, and in there rebuild the entire DOM each time that is triggered.

```
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  // Clear the DOM

  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    // Add to the DOM
  })
})
```

Alternatively, you can use `on("child_` listeners, that are triggered on the individual child nodes, and make the individual DOM modifications for each.

```
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, peviousChildKey) {
  // Add to the DOM
})
ref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot, peviousChildKey) {
  // Update in the DOM
})
ref.on("child_removed", function(snapshot) {
  // Remove from the DOM
})
ref.on("child_moved", function(snapshot, peviousChildKey) {
  // Move in the DOM
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this does not solve the efficiency problem. I have updated the question with code.

Comment: When you listen to `child_` events, you no longer need the `listElement.innerHTML = “”` and you end up processing only changes. If you don't see that happening, update your question with what you've tried.

Comment: I have the feeling that you don't quite understand the answer I'm looking for. I understand they it would be quite simple to add, remove or change existing elements based on the child listeners; however, the workflow isn't that simple where the changes are one-to-one to what is shown in the page. Removing is quite simple is I'll just have to delete the element (though it could remove a whole row entirely), but how would I handle adding and changing? Adding a new element requires adding it to the correct row in the correct sorted order. Changing could move an element from one row to another.

Comment: Ah, you'd use the previous child key for that. I added them to the signatures in my answer and they're also mentioned here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#on.

Comment: But the children in database are not stored in any meaningful way. The sorting of elements depend on the properties stored in the `.sortBy` and `.groupBy` properties and is done locally in the browser. Are you proposing that I change the way that the data is stored on the database? How would this work if the sort order changes? Do I have to completely overwrite all the data in the lists of objects and create new keys? How would I insert a new object with a key that is in between its neighbors? Would I delete and change the object's key based on sort order? Is this on browser or backend?

Comment: So in that case you'll have to determine where to insert it yourself on the client, in the same way that Firebase determines the `previousChildKey`. But in that case the problem seems fairly unrelated to Firebase, which is what I was trying to help with.